# add method followed by previous method does not gave any output while using ArrayList listIterator method in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

```java
package listIterator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(10);
    list.add(20);
    list.add(30);
    
    // this code will not work
    ListIterator<Integer> it;

        System.out.println("using add");
        it = list.listIterator(list.size());
        while(it.hasPrevious()) {
            it.add(5);
            it.previous();
            
        }
        System.out.println(list);   
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this an infinite loop? You keep adding item before the cursor.

Comment: Code-only questions are not recommended. You need to explain your problem more in post.

Answer (score 0):

## infinite loop

As stated in [a Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76988565/add-method-followed-by-previous-method-does-not-gave-any-output-while-using-arra#comment135720700_76988565)…

Your code is in an infinite loop, always adding an element, and always having a previous element.

Your test `while( it.hasPrevious() )` always returns `true`. After you add an element, you move the cursor back with a call to `previous`.

Use a debugger and/or some println commands to watch the cursor of your iterator.